# Javascript -- find object with element of a specific value

Tags: javascript

I am working on an application that gets an id number -- and then I need to find the object that an element with an id.
so if I have the value 6 --- I want to gain access to the correct object in this array so I can then read service_name

```
[{
"id": 2,
"service_name": "benny"
},{
"id": 5,
"service_name": "ready"
},{
"id": 6,
"service_name": "chitty"
},{
"id": 9,
"service_name": "robby"
}]
```

Comment: Please [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+find+object+array+property) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Can you try with `Array.find`

Comment: Assuming `obj` is the obj (parse the json to obj like `JSON.parse(obj)` before you do this), `obj.find(item => item.id === 6)` should get you the item... But this is standard JS and is easily found here with more examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: thanks man - did the trick

Comment: Just to mention. Even though this question is a duplicate it was the first google result since it used the "element" and not "by id" keyword.

So people looking for it will find a solution here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Array.find()

```js
const arr = [{
"id": 2,
"service_name": "benny"
},{
"id": 5,
"service_name": "ready"
},{
"id": 6,
"service_name": "chitty"
},{
"id": 9,
"service_name": "robby"
}]


const six = arr.find(i => i.id === 6)

console.log(six.service_name)
```